# How do we Link two html files(not href link)..i mean an html document to another html document

Tags: html, css

I want to use a table in 3 web pages .So I was thinking of making a different html document for the table and adiing it to  all those pages.How to do that?

Comment: do you mean 3 cells in a table and on each cell there are 3 different webpages?

Comment: not really...one table is used in three diff web pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating the html page with the table, add this to all three pages:

```
<iframe src="table_page.html"></iframe>
```

Set the src as the name of the html page that has the table. You can also add custom width, height etc.

Comment: how can we access the table data from the table present inside the html doc table_page.html?

Answer (score 0):

iframes are an option which has already been detailed out. If you want to actually load an HTML page into another one you could use JQuery's load function:

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html" );
```

You can read more on JQuery's documentation - http://api.jquery.com/load/